# How do you randomly assign data into equal sized control and treatment groups in R?

Tags: r

```
set.seed(31)
resample(1:534, 90, replace = FALSE)

df.orig <- read.csv("project1data.csv")

df.groups <- filter(df.orig, participate == "y")
str(df.groups)
```

I have randomly selected 90 house numbers from 534 and entered whether or not they were willing to participate in the study into an excel sheet and then I filtered out the people who did not want to participate in the study. How do I now randomly assign the participants into two equally sized groups (control and treatment)

Comment: What packages are you using? The functions `resample` and `filter` occur in multiple packages. Also provide some reproducible data, not the name of a file that we cannot access. Since the sample was drawn randomly, you can take the first 1/2 of the values for one group and the second 1/2 for the other group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided data or code that runs so I'll generate some code to show the idea

```
set.seed(31)
# Create dataset with three variables
# Participate are the ones that we wish to include in the study. 
# You have those in your excel file.

fakedata <- data.frame(houseid=1:534, 
                       size=rbinom(534, size=5, prob=.5),
                       participate=sample(c("y", "n"), size=534, replace=TRUE))
```

which produces

```
head(fakedata)
  houseid size participate
1       1    3           y
2       2    4           n
3       3    2           n
4       4    2           y
5       5    4           y
6       6    2           n
```

Now we can use `tidyverse` to generate a random permutation of cases/controls. First we create a vector of the correct length (using `rep` with length) and then we shuffle them using `sample`.

```r
library("tidyverse")
fakedata %>%  # Take data
  filter(participate=="y") %>% 
  mutate(group=sample(rep(c("Case", "Ctrl"), length=n())))
```

This gives

```
    houseid size participate group
1         1    3           y  Case
2         4    2           y  Case
3         5    4           y  Ctrl
4         7    4           y  Case
5         8    1           y  Case
6         9    4           y  Ctrl
7        13    3           y  Case
8        16    1           y  Ctrl
.
.
.
```